# Hide specific columns script google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I would like to ignore the first three columns (A, B, and C) with this script. The end result would be to hide all columns that have a date header and the date has already passed.  The script below does hide all of the columns up to the current date but it also hides the three columns that contain names.  Any thoughts?

```
    function onOpen(e) {
      var sheet = e.source.getSheetByName('Sheet1'); // or .getSheets()[0]; to apply to the first sheet.
      var width = sheet.getDataRange().getWidth();
      var dates = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, width).getValues().valueOf();  
      var today = Date.now();
      var minDiff = 1e9;
      var imin = 0;
     for (var i = 0; i < dates[0].length; i++) {
      if (Math.abs(dates[0][i]-today) < minDiff) {
          imin = i;
          minDiff = Math.abs(dates[0][i]-today);
        }
      }
      sheet.hideColumns(1, imin-1);
    }
```

Comment: `sheet.hideColumns(1,...)` will always hide starting at ColA. If you want to start hiding at ColD, then use `sheet.hideColumns(4,...)`. The first parameter is the index from which to start hiding.

Comment: Awesome!  I'm still trying to figure out the whole scripting...Glad it was a simple switch! Thanks!